# Bluetooth Android Image/file transfer

Tags: java, android, image, bluetooth, data-transfer

I am doing an app that would be able to receive images and files using bluetooth connection. I don't want to send anything, only receive. All online codes are for sending. Im sending from Mac and image for testing to an android device (Epson glasses) app. please help. I have provided the code below. Sockets connection is established.

```
public class Mine extends Activity {


private TextView SampleText;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
public static final UUID Glasses_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final String TAG = "debugging";
static final int IMAGE_QUALITY = 100;
ImageView pointerIcon;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
private final String TEMP_IMAGE_FILE_NAME = "BTimage.jpg" + timeStamp +"_";


//Handler used to send data to here
// it converts byte array to string and saves it to write message
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i(TAG, "---In Handler---");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what) {
            //do something

            case 1:
                ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                mConnectedThread.start();
                break;


            case 2:

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), readMessage, duration).show();
                break;


            case 3:   //data received -image

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(((byte[]) msg.obj), 0, ((byte[]) msg.obj).length, options);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                break;

        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);

    //sets the background as transparent black
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    winParams.flags |= 0x80000000;
    win.setAttributes(winParams);


    SampleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SampleText);
    pointerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    SampleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(200); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    SampleText.startAnimation(anim);




    // BLUETOOTH section

    //make device discoverable for 300sec
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300); // for extra time discovery
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "---Making device discoverable for 300 seconds---");

    // get local bluetooth (glasses)
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    //checks if bluetooth is enabled, if its not it enables it

       if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
           Intent EnableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
           startActivityForResult(EnableBluetooth, 1);
           ///Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Enabled", duration).show();
           Log.i(TAG, "---Bluetooth is now on---");

           finish();

       } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Already On", duration).show();
       }


// get list of paired devices
// The paired device is saved into storage "Set".
   Set <BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    //if there is paired devices


    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        //loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            mmDevice = device;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paired Device: " + device.getName() + device.getAddress(),
                    duration).show();
          Log.i(TAG, "---Show on screen Device connected");


        }
    }

    ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mmDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;  // temporary object assigned to mmSocket later
        mmDevice = device;
        Log.i(TAG, "---Connecting---");
        UUID SERIAL_UUID = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid(); // to identify the app uuid
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(SERIAL_UUID));

        //Get Bluetooth socket to connect with a bluetooth device
        try {
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Glasses_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create Socket failed!", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {

        Log.i(TAG, "---BEGIN ConnectThread - RUN() ---");
        setName("ConnectThread");


        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();   // because it slows down a connection

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            Log.i(TAG, "---Connecting to socket...----");
            ///mmDevice= mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("68:A8:6D:2B:77:FD");
            if(!mmSocket.isConnected())  //to prevent connecting again and again
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "---Connected to Socket...----");
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1, mmSocket).sendToTarget();

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out


            try {

                Log.i(TAG, "---Unable to connect, Socket Closing...----");
                mmSocket.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "---Socket Closed----");
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "--unable to close socket!--", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }
        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        // start thread
    }

    /**
     * Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket
     */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "---closing socket failed!---", e);
        }
    }
}

/**

 *
 *  Send and receive data Thread
 *  Handles all incoming transmissions.
 */
  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final InputStream mmInStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.i(TAG, "---ConnectedThread Start----");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        // get the temporary input streams
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "---getting input tmp----");
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();               //getinput stream gives accesss to the socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "---Error getting streams!----", e);
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
    }

    public void run () {
        Log.i(TAG, "---BEGIN ConnectedThread - Run()---");
        int bufferSize= 2097152; //This is set to 2 MB
        byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; //bytes returned from read()

        ByteArrayOutputStream compressedImageStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {

                // Read from the InputStream
                Log.i(TAG, "---Reading Data...---");

                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];     // buffer store for stream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);   // bytes returned from read()



                compressedImageStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                //Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
               // mHandler.obtainMessage(2, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();




                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_IMAGE_FILE_NAME);   // create image file in storage - destination path and filename
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);   // this is to read the image from the storage /decoding


                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, IMAGE_QUALITY, compressedImageStream); //save as PNG or JPEG here
                byte[] compressedImage = compressedImageStream.toByteArray();
                Log.v(TAG, "Compressed image size: " + compressedImage.length);


                Message message = new Message();
                message.obj = compressedImage;
                mHandler.sendMessage(message);


                // Display the image locally

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

                //Intent intent=new Intent();
                //intent.setAction("received");
                //sendBroadcast(intent);

                Log.i(TAG, "---reading data successful---");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "---disconnected!---(Reading problem)", e);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with? Are you getting specific errors?

Comment: I send the image and it is not received and display on the screen in the app. I don't think that the app is reading from the stream. I don't think my code is complete. (no errors in logcat when its run).